# const yaml-cpp node changes when used multiple times

Tags: c++, yaml-cpp

For a .yaml, say

```
aaa:
    bbb:
        ccc: testOne
        ddd: testTwo
```

the goal is to find the value for a given parameter path, e.g. aaa/bbb/ccc. When I try to do this twice, although passing a const YAML::Node around, the parent aaa is changed and points, where I was last searching.
I understood YAML::Nodes are only a shallow structure and thus my operations are obviously changing the underlying data. What would be the neat way to navigate through the tree without changing the input data ?

See my minimal example with some debug output for more details:

```
std::string findNodeInYAMLTree(const YAML::Node node, const std::vector<std::string> &pathInTree)
{
    std::cout << "Input root node for findNodeInYAMLTree():" << std::endl;
    for (const auto& kv : node) {
        std::cout << kv.first.as<std::string>() << "\n";
    }

    YAML::Node parentNode = node;
    YAML::Node childNode = parentNode;
    std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator it = pathInTree.begin();
    while (it != pathInTree.end()) {
        std::string childNodeName = *it;
        if (!parentNode.IsDefined() || !parentNode[childNodeName]) {
            std::cout << "Did not find the next tree path node <" << childNodeName << ">" << std::endl;
            return "Failure";
        }
        childNode = parentNode[childNodeName];
        parentNode = childNode;
        it++;
    }
    return childNode.as<std::string>();
}

void testSameFctTwice()
{
    YAML::Node aaa;
    YAML::Node node = YAML::Load("aaa: {bbb: {ccc: testOne, ddd: testTwo}}");
    std::vector<std::string> testOneStr({"aaa", "bbb","ccc"});
    std::cout << findNodeInYAMLTree(node, testOneStr) << std::endl;
    std::vector<std::string> testTwoStr({"aaa", "bbb", "ddd"});
    std::cout << findNodeInYAMLTree(node, testTwoStr) << std::endl;
}
```

I am using the system-repo's version 0.5.2, temporarily updating yaml-cpp to 0.6/HEAD did not change things.

The output will be:

```
Input root node for findNodeInYAMLTree():
aaa
testOne
Input root node for findNodeInYAMLTree():
ddd
ccc
Did not find the next tree path node <aaa>
Failure
```

So the workaround is:

```
    YAML::Node parentNode = YAML::Clone(node);
```

But I feel like this could be done better.

Comment: presumably `findNodeInYAMLTree(const YAML::Node node,` should be `findNodeInYAMLTree(const YAML::Node& node,`?

Comment: maybe change `parentNode` and `childNode` to pointers? I guess `childNode = parentNode[childNodeName]` is copying the contents of `parentNode[childNodeName]` into `childNode`, not a very friendly thing for a library to do it thats the case

Comment: As for the Reference YAML::Node &node passing, not helping. YAML::Node is nothing mroe than a bool and two pointers anyway.

Comment: I dont manage to write a pointer version, because of compiler errors of "taking address of temporary". The operator[ ] in parentNode[childNodeName] creates a Node() in that scope. I guess this is not the way to go, because parentNode[childNodeName] is the only operation that could be changing the input data, but is not replaced when using pointers. Thanks @AlanBirtles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In yaml-cpp, `operator =` assigns a reference value. This is a little unintuitive; see [this issue](https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp/issues/208) discussing the problem.

Instead, call `Node::reset`:

```
childNode.reset(parentNode[childNodeName]);
```

Comment: unintuitive. true ;) This could need better documentation (doxygen api?), since your lib has really good functionality, but usability is a bit behind. Cheers for actively supporting here.